# GWT, Guice and GIN compilation

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I'm trying to build and GWT MVP application using Guice and Gin. I added Guice and GIN jars to my Eclipse project but i'm stuck with this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions
```

I've done a quick Google search and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/2484550628c20624) says the we need to recompile GIN against GWT SDK. Also, the [Gin Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial) mention something about a compilation step.

Isn't enough to add GIN jars to the GWT project, or is mandatory to generate gin.jar from sources? How do i accomplish this with Eclipse (with Google Plugin)?

PS: I'm not using Maven in my Project. Only Eclipse and Google Tools
Another PS: Currently using Guice 3.0, Gin 1.5 and GWT 2.3

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.3. As concerns Gin, i've added gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar and Guice related JARS. Is that enough?

Comment: Error has gone. Guice-3.0.jar was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `GWT 2.2` or above try using a latest snapshot of  `gin 1.1` or higher versions and also upgrade `guice 3.0`.

Comment: Latest of Gin is 1.5, released a year ago - http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

For Gin 1.5 there is a pre-gwt-2.2 jar and a post-gwt-2.2 jar.  Make sure you have the right one.  And probably only one of them should be in the WEB-INF/lib.  Make sure both gin and guice are in the lib and in Java Build Path->Libraries.  I also have aopalliance.jar, guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar and javax.inject.jar. (Also guice-servlet but that isn't part of the problem here).  Make sure you have " "  in your .gwt.xml file.

And remember in dev mode that gin uses guice to do most of the work.