# NoClassDefFoundError with Gin 1.5 and GWT 2.4

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I am trying to put together a GWT webapp following [this GWT MVP tutorial](http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/08/google-web-toolkit-gwt-mvp-example.html) but using newer releases of the used libraries because not all of them are available any more or not compatible with GWT 2.4.

The problem is that when I run the project, I get the following to the console:

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
[WARN] failed com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@6ee76fcc{/,/home/raido/Kood/workspaceJava/gwtmvp/war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:44)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:113)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:101)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:105)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:76)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:63)
at gwtmvp.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig.getInjector(GuiceServletConfig.java:11)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:373)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
... 30 more
[WARN] failed RequestLogHandler@4113a03d
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:44)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:113)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:101)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:105)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:76)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:63)
at gwtmvp.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig.getInjector(GuiceServletConfig.java:11)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:373)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
... 30 more
[WARN] Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Preconditions
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:44)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:113)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:101)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:105)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:76)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:63)
at gwtmvp.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig.getInjector(GuiceServletConfig.java:11)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:373)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
... 30 more
```

Libraries needed for the projects vs libraries I have:

- gin.jar --- **gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar** (gin-1.5)
- aopalliance.jar  (from Google Gin) --- **aopalliance.jar** (gin-1.5)
- guice-2.0.jar (from Google Gin. IMPORTANT - use the version supplied with Gin and not Guice) --- **guice-snapshot.jar** (gin-1.5)
- guice-servlet-2.0.jar (from Google Guice) --- **guice-servlet-3.0.jar** (guice-3.0)
- gwt-dispatch-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  (from gwt-dispatch) --- **gwt-dispatch-1.2.0.jar**
- gwt-log-2.6.2.jar (from gwt-log) --- **gwt-log-3.1.8.jar**
- gwt-presenter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (from gwt-presenter) --- **gwt-presenter-1.0.0.jar**
- log4j.jar (from log4j) --- **log4j-1.2.16.jar**

Gwt-presenter also has a newer version, 1.1.1 which caused additional problems so I went back to 1.0.0 but that is an another story.

I have the code uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/Raidok/gwtmvp). Most of it is just copy-paste from the mentioned tutorial with minor differences.

Comment: I am getting a little further with [gin-1.0 when compiled with post-2.2 GWT compiler](http://populationjim.com/2011/02/14/how-to-make-gwt-2-2-work-with-gin/) but this isn't the answer to my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries you have posted

```
guice-2.0.jar (from Google Gin. IMPORTANT - use the version supplied with Gin and not Guice) --- guice-snapshot.jar (gin-1.5)
guice-servlet-2.0.jar (from Google Guice) --- guice-servlet-3.0.jar (guice-3.0)
```

seems colliding. It seems you have `Guice 2.0.jar` and `Guice 3.0.jar` both in your classpath.
Keep only `Guice 3.0.jar`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Collision it was. I replaced all Guice snapshot versions which were bundeled with Gin with Guice 3.0 jars and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the same tutorial, I tried to use more recent JARS like you did and I found the same errors as you as you can see here: [GWT, Guice and GIN compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403815/gwt-guice-and-gin-compilation). The issue was caused because some missing JARS, specifically **Guice-3.0.jar**.

Very that the required JAR is in your classpath: that should fix the problem.